# Unix suid bit problem

Tags: c, unix

I have written a program in c, that do some calculations then creates a folder. That folder's owner is the root user. With an other user I am trying to run this c application. I've got this error:

```
mkdir: lol: Permission denied
```

Ok, I know this error is ok, because I don't have rights for it, but I have read on the internet, that if I set the suid bit on the file, then this file will run with the owner's rights.
I've used this command:

```
chmod +s filename
```

But it isn't working... :( Any ideas?

EDIT:
So, first of all, my Unix distribution is a Mac OS X 10.5.8. And my filename is a.out, since I have compiled it from ic.c with the command: `gcc ic.c`
And I am running the chmod command with the root user.

Comment: Are you running the `chmod` as root?

Comment: Is root the owner of your binary? Nevertheless, really, rethink your problem and ask yourself whether setuid bit is really needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you also will need to `setuid(0);` in your program to become root. Only setting the s-bit is not sufficient.

> I agree with all others, that doing all these things is very risky...

**Edit**

Jonathan Leffler is right in the comments. `setuid(0);` should probably not be necessary in this case. The necessary steps for ie creating a file under `/etc`

#### create_file_under_etc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  FILE *fp = fopen("/etc/so-su-test.txt", "wt");
  if (fp) {
    fprintf(fp, "I'll be back\n");
    fclose(fp);
    printf("File created.\n");
  } else {
    printf("File not created.\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

...and to test and compile

```
cc create_file_under_etc.c
sudo chmod +s a.out
sudo chown root:staff a.out
./a.out
```

...you better clean up also

```
sudo rm a.out
sudo rm /etc/so-su-test.txt
```

Comment: Yes, it is risky, I know this, but I want this, because I need to present this security hole for somebody.

Comment: Using setuid(0) is sometimes necessary - but probably not in this case.  The key thing is setting the SUID bit on the executable.  The setuid(0); call sets both the real and effective (and saved) UID to 0, root.  There's not much trace of the user that started the process left.  It is dangerous to do that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In which cases *is* it necessary? I had problems with a program that called other programs (via system()), which didn't run with the set uid, but rather with the original. Are there other cases?

Comment: @Creshal: You shouldn't have a problem unless SUID program P1 (SUID 0, say) runs another program SUID program P2 (SUID 4, say), but you want P2 to consider that root (0) ran P2. Normally, if one SUID program runs another, the second will run with the real UID of the person who ran the first. If you want the second to think the real UID was the SUID of the first, then you need to get the real UID set on P1 (perhaps after the fork but before the exec, in which case you can't use `system()` after all), and the `setuid(0);` would be necessary. Otherwise, AFAIK, it isn't needed (but is convenient).

Comment: I did everything but `sudo chown root`. That solved my issue. +1

Answer (score 2):

Well, you don't say what 'filename' is. You can only suid on an executable. Particularly you can't set it on a shell script - it has to be a real machine code executable. And in modern UNIXes, like some horrible Linux distros, you might not be able to set it at all without jumping through more hoops than you might like.

Comment: So, first of all, my Unix distribution is a Mac OS X 10.5.8. And my filename is a.out, since I have compiled it from ic.c with the command:
gcc ic.c

Comment: Sorry Mac OS != UNIX in my book. Any help I could give you ends here.

Comment: @Infinity Just realised that sounded a bit rude - not intentional, it's just that Mac OS is a long, long way away from UNIX, and I know zip about it.

Comment: But most of the unix commands work in Mac OS X, that's why I thought that is true that Mac OS X is built on Unix.

Comment: @Infinity Most of the UNIX commands work just fine on Windows too - they are just simple programs that you are I could write. But interacting with the authentication and permission systems, which is what setting the suid bit has to do, will typically involve stuff particular to your specific OS. And like I said, I know nothing about Mac OS.

Comment: Mac OS is basically FreeBSD at this level... and it actually IS a real Unix, unlike Linux.  But yes, it is pretty unusual in some ways, especially the linker.  In any case, it's very faithfully POSIX so far as basic security semantics is concerned.

Comment: As someone who just had to use the terminal window to `ps` for a stalled process (Yahoo Messenger) and use the `kill` command on it ... I can confirm that MacOS X is UNIX.  It puts some stuff in some pretty odd places in the filesystem.  But it's UNIX nonetheless.

Comment: Mac OS is not UNIX and is a totally different OS. Mac OS X, on the other hand, is UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

Try running chmod as the root user.

I've been bit by this in the past:(

Comment: Yes, I am running the chmod as root.

Answer (score 1):

There is a incorrect syntax. Command must be lock like chmod u+s filename
Wizard for chmod http://en.clihelper.com/chmod/ can help with syntax of chmod

Comment: interesting tool you have there @user3875999.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question exactly what "filename" is referring to -- the executable,
or the directory you want to create files in?  To do what you want, you need to use the
`chmod +s` command on the executable, so it will run with root privileges.  `chmod +s` on the target directory won't do anything to open up the file creation privileges to non-root users.

The whole concept strikes me as a bit of a security risk, though -- wouldn't it be better
for root to create a directory somewhere just for this application, then chmod it 775 or 777 to grant write permission to "group" or "world" respectively?

**Edit**:  I see that you're indeed trying to chmod the executable, and that you're running
the chmod command as root.  But does root own the executable?  You might need a "chown"
command (as root) in addition to the chmod +s command, to ensure that it runs setuid root
instead of setuid whoever-built-the-executable.

Comment: So I have set the +s bit on my executable file. Also used the setuid(0) command in the source code. And is working as I want. Btw I am trying to reproduce a security hole, because I need to present it to somebody. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the root user owns the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You used the command

```
chmod +s filename
```

The syntax you used to issue that command is incorrect. The correct syntax would be

```
chmod [ugoa]+s filename
```

where you can use any combination of the letters u, g, o, and a.

Unix, as you already know, stores information about permissions for each folder/file. There are permissions for read, write, execute, sticky, and more attached to each file. For a single file, there is a different set of permissions for the owner, group, and everyone else. So, while the owner of a file may be able to read, write, and execute a file, all other users in the owner's group might be able to only read that file, and everyone else might not be able to access that file at all.

When issuing the chmod command, you need to specify which set of users you are changing the permissions for. Do this by using a combination of the letters u, g, o, and a. 'u' changes permissions for the owner of the file, 'g' for all users in the owner's group, 'o' for all other users outside the owner's group, and 'a' for all three sets of users.

Examples:

`chmod ga-r confidential.txt` will make it so that only the owner of the file will be able to read 'confidential.txt'. All other users, including users in the owners group, will not be able to read 'confidential.txt'

`chmod ga-rwx really_confidential.txt` will make it so that anyone, other than the owner of that file, will not be able to read, write, or execute 'really_confidential.txt'. Put another way, you are *removing* the ability to read, write, or execute 'really_confidential.txt' from all users except owner.

`chmod u+s filename` adds the sticky bit to 'filename', only for the owner of that file.

EDIT: Oh yeah, and since the file is owned by root, make sure to preface the command you issue with a 'sudo'. But it looks like you already know that.

Comment: Actually, the `[ugoa]` (aka who) part is optional for chmod. Not given will set/reset all possible bits for the +/- permission.

Comment: Well. Shows how much I know.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not at home at the moment, but when I get home I'll try it. It is interesting what did you write.